# Which JavaScript library does GWT use?

Tags: java, gwt

Which library does GWT use when compiling Java code to JavaScript? (For example ExtGwt outputs ExtJS code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT itself has a set of UI widgets, have a look [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefWidgetGallery.html), and the source code is [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user).

Answer (score 0):

GWT **is** the library.

BTW, ExtGWT doesn't "output ExtJS code", it's a *port* of ExtJS to Java/GWT.